# Generators of $SL_2 (F_q)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-fields, linear-groups

I am working on the following problem.

> Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field with $q \neq 9$ elements and $a$ be a generator of the cyclic group $\mathbb{F}_q^{\times}$. Show that $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is generated by
>   \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 1 \\
> 0 & 1 \\
> \end{pmatrix}
>   and
>   \begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 0 \\
> a & 1 \\
> \end{pmatrix}

My attempt is to make upper-triangular matrixes and lower-triangular matrixes from these elements, because $\mathrm{SL}_2(K)$ is generated from triangular matrixes for any field $K$. When $q$ is prime, we can obtain every triangular matrixes by multiplying these two elements.

However, I don't see how to proceed when $q = p^n$. Since $|\mathrm{SL}_2(K)| = q^3-q$ and  the order of two elements above is $p$, my attempt fails. I also don't  see how the assumption that $q \neq 9$  works.

Comment: This has been proved by Dickson. The proof is in Susuki's  book "Group Theory Volume 1", 3 (6.21).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks. I've looked at Suzuki's book and (although I haven't understood the details) it seems for me that he assumes $p$ is odd. How Suzuki's method would be when $p=2$?

Comment: This is indeed true when $q=9$, so I don't know why this has been excluded.