# Alternative reference for generators of ${\rm SL}(2,q)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, alternative-proof

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3648182/104041) (and its comments) put forward the following information:

> **Theorem:** Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field with odd $q\neq 9$ elements and $a$ be a generator of the cyclic group $\mathbb{F}_q^{\times}$. Show that $\mathrm{SL}(2,q)$ is generated by
> $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 1 \\
> 0 & 1 \\
> \end{pmatrix}$$
> and
> $$B=\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 0 \\
> a & 1 \\
> \end{pmatrix}.$$

and a proof can be found in Suzuki's, *"Group Theory I"*.

I would like to see a proof soon or, at any rate, have access to one; but I can't get a hold of Suzuki's book. It isn't at my university library. I have a physical copy of my own. It's with a relative in England, though, and I'm currently in Scotland. Hence the [alternative-proof](/questions/tagged/alternative-proof) tag: I want an alternative reference, please.

If the proof is simple, please share it, although I haven't warranted such an answer with enough context.

*Some thoughts:*

The way I'd try to prove it is to look at the forms of the conjugacy classes of ${\rm SL}(2,q)$ then attempt to construct their representatives from $A$ and $B$, to see what ideas come to mind.

Comment: Is the statement correct? As long as $a\in\mathbb F_q^\times$, the group that $B$ generates does not change.

Comment: I believe so, but, of course, I haven't seen a proof, @KentaS! I trust Derek Holt and Dietrich Burde in the comments of the linked question for now.

Comment: I don't think it's supposed to change, @KentaS.

Comment: I am pointing out that the hypothesis that $a$ generates $\mathbb F_q^\times$ is not doing anything.

Comment: Oh sorry it makes a difference when $q$ is a prime power; it does not make a difference when $q$ is prime.

Comment: My university library has a copy of *"Finite groups,"* by Gorenstein. It might be in there. I won't find out until at least Monday.

Comment: Gorenstein at 2.8.4 in my 1968 edition states it as a theorem of Dickson and proves it. There is, btw,  an exceptional case - when $q=9$ we get $SL(2,5)$. The proof is too long for me to transcribe for you.

Comment: Shaun, I have sent a photocopy of the relevant pages to your university email.

Comment: Excellent!  Yes, I just replied via email, @ancientmathematician. Thank you!

Comment: libgen.is ... Just saying 

Comment: The statement in Dickson/Gorenstein/Suzuki assumes that $a$ generates $\mathbb{F}_q$ over the prime field (but is not necessarily a generator of $\mathbb{F}_q^\times$). Then the result is that $A$ and $B$ generate $SL(2,q)$, except when $q = 9$ and $a^2 = -1$. So if $a$ is a generator of $\mathbb{F}_q^\times$, then $A$ and $B$ always generate $SL(2,q)$.